# How to put datas from MongoDB into an object with Casbah and Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I want to put in a "User" class datas from MongoDB. `find()` method doesn't return the type I want.

I have a piece of code, I don't know how i can use it :

```
def findUser(username: String) : Option[User] =
  {
    var user:Option[User] = None
    val userToFind = MongoDBObject("username" -> username)
    users.findOne(userToFind).foreach { x =>
      user = Some(new User(x("username").toString,x("password").toString,x("firstname").toString, x("lastname").toString, true,2))
    }
    user
  }
```

How to use my result to put into my object parameters ?

this is my Object User :

```
class User (
  val username    : String,
  var password    : String,
  var firstname   : String,
  var lastname    : String,
  var isActivated : Boolean,
  val tenantId    : Int
             )
{}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for example like this:

```
def findUser(username: String): Option[User] = {
    val result = mongoCollUser.findOne(MongoDBObject("username"->username));
    result.map { user => toUser(user)  }
  }


  def toUser(dbObject:DBObject) : User = {
      User(dbObject.as[String]("username"),dbObject.as[String]("password"),dbObject.as[String]("firstname"),dbObject.as[String]("lastname"),dbObject.as[Boolean]("isActivated"),dbObject.as[Int]("tenantId"))
  }

case class User (
             val username    : String,
             var password    : String,
             var firstname   : String,
             var lastname    : String,
             var isActivated : Boolean,
             val tenantId    : Int
             )
```

Comment: Darn, I was hoping that toUser wouldn't be necessary - it sure would be nice in there were something like dbObject.as[User]